# Card Game: Two Slightly Different Expected Value derivavations

Tags: probability

For Christmas my family have been playing a card game called [Wordaround](http://thinkfun.com/products/wordaround/). The rules are irrelevant here, other than the fact that each card has $3$ words printed on it and there are $100$ cards. In each "game" of Wordaround, we use exactly one word from each of the $100$ cards. The method by which words are chosen is not important here, so assume each word is chosen with uniform probability of $\frac13$.

Now, after a few games of this, we realised that we were encountering the same words again and again. This is not hard to believe, since it's possible to exhaust all words in exactly $3$ games, though it's quite unlikely. Being obsessed with maths, I was naturally inclined to try and work out the expected value of the number of "unused" words after $n$ games. I began with a simple argument, but was unconvinced, so tried a more complex argument. The two answers agreed, but I'm not sure I'm entirely correct in my first derivation.

#### My First Attempt: Words are Events

The simple (perhaps naive) approach I took first was to consider the $300$ words as true/false events for each game. In each game, a word has $\frac23$ probability of **not** being picked. Since choices of a word in successive games are independent events, we can then say that after $n$ games, a word has a $(\frac23)^n$ chance of **not** being chosen. So the expected value of unused words is just the sum of all the individual expected values i.e. $300(\frac23)^n$. This agrees with a simple observation: after one round, there will be exactly $200$ unused words. But I think I made a subtle mistake here, because choosing one word on a card mutually excludes the choice of the other two.

#### My Second Attempt: Words left per Card

To ease my worries I calculated the probability a different way. Consider a card and ask: how many unused words are left on it after $n$ games? Clearly after $1$ game, there are exactly $2$ unused words. Let's assume $n \geq 1$. Then there are either $0, 1$ or $2$ unused words. The expected number of unused words is the probability that there is $1$ unused word plus twice the probability that there are $2$ unused words.

The probability of two unused words is the chance that the same word was chosen for all games i.e. for the remaining $n-1$ games the first word repeats, yielding:

$$\left(\frac13\right)^{n-1} = \frac{3}{3^n}$$

The probability of $1$ unused card can be calculated by considering first the number of $n$ digit ternary numbers that use only two digits- excluding numbers that use only one digit. This number is $3 \cdot (2^n - 2)$. That is: $3$ ways to exclude a number, and $(2^n - 2)$ subsets of $n$ corresponding to the choices for the indices of the smaller number remaining, excluding the $2$ corner cases where all indices are the same digit. Dividing this by the total number of ternary $n$ digit numbers gives us the probability.

$$\dfrac{3 \cdot (2^n - 2)}{3^n}$$

So the expected value per card is:

$$2 \cdot \frac{3}{3^n} + \dfrac{3 \cdot (2^n - 2)}{3^n} = \dfrac{3 \cdot (2^n)}{3^n}$$

Multiplying by $100$ cards and we get:

$$300(\frac23)^n$$

Which agrees with the answer derived by the first method.

#### Question

Are both methods valid paths to the correct answer or is the first answer just a fluke?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The first answer has correct reasoning, as well. Your doubt stems from the (true) fact that the survival of one word is not independent from survival of another on the same card. But expectation values are additive, even when the underlying variables are not independent.

Answer (score 1):

Both are valid ways to get the answer. A valid justification for the first method goes as follows:

For each of the 300 words ($1 \leq i \leq 300$), let $X_{i,n}$ be the random variable which is $1$ if the $i$-th word has never been chosen after $n$ games, and $0$ otherwise.
As you stated, $E(X_{i,n}) =\text{Pr}(X_{i,n} = 1) = \left(\frac{2}{3}\right)^n.$

Now, the number of unused words after $n$ games is clearly $\sum_{i=1}^{300} X_{i,n}$, hence the expected number of unused words is
$$E\left(\sum_{i=1}^{300}X_{i,n}\right) = \sum_{i=1}^{300}E(X_{i,n}) = 300 \left(\frac{2}{3}\right)^n$$